# From code below how can i apply reusability to the javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

javascript

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("next").onclick=function() {
    document.getElementById("out_est_value").innerHTML=document.getElementById("est_value").value;
    document.getElementById("out_int_est_value").innerHTML=document.getElementById("est_value").value*0.75;
  }
}
```

input

```
<label>Estimated value of property:</label><input type="text" name="est_value" id="est_value" maxlength="30"class="required number"value=""/> <br>
```

output

```
<p> You told us the estimated value of your property is &pound;<span class="red" id="out_est_value"></span> based on this we estimate that the initial cash offer is likely be around &pound;<span class="red" id="out_int_est_value"></span>.<p>
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Which part of the code do you want to reuse in the future?

Comment: I want to reuse the value of "est_value" and display it on another span

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever possible, store objects which are found in the DOM (e.g. `getElementById(x)`) or accessed by looking up properties (e.g. `element.value`) in a separate variable if they will be accessed multiple times (essentially "reusing" them instead of finding them again).  Doing so will increase the readability and performance of your code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var estVal = document.getElementById("est_value")
    , outEstVal = document.getElementById("out_est_value")
    , outIntEstVal = document.getElementById("out_int_est_value");
  document.getElementById("next").onclick = function() {
    var val = estVal.value;
    outEstVal.innerHTML = val;
    outIntEstVal.innerHTML = val * 0.75;
  };
};
```

Also, if you are really using jQuery then embrace the convenient things it does for you (it's really worth it!), such as finding DOM elements, adding event handlers, setting HTML contents, etc.  Doing this will likely improve the maintainability of your code for yourself and other developers and help you avoid common cross-browser pitfalls:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var estVal = $("#est_value")
    , outEstVal = $("#out_est_value")
    , outIntEstVal = $("#out_int_est_value");
  $("#next").click(function() {
    var val = estVal.val();
    outEstVal.html(val);
    outIntEstVal.html(val * 0.75);
  });
});
```

Comment: You can use `.html()` instead of `.innerHTML` for the jQuery part.

Comment: @Ben Alpert: yup, just fixed that jQueryism... =)

Comment: @Ben Alpert: the code above doesnt work

Comment: however, this piece of code of yours is phenomenal thank you sir :)

Comment: @tony: here is a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k2J8j/) using my code example above.

Comment: I finally realize why it would not display on other span its because of id tag. :)